# Running Single instance AppScale in a virtual machine

Tags: java, appscale

I was trying to run AppScale in a Single-instance node installed in a Vmware box and running the appscale-tools in the same server virtual machine and got this error:

```
root@appscale:~appscale-tools-bin# ./appscale-run-instances --ips ips.yaml
About to start AppScale over a non-cloud environment.
Head node successfully created at 127.0.0.1. It is now starting up cassandra via the command line arguments given.
Generating certificate and private key
Starting server at 127.0.0.1 
Please wait for the controller to finish pre-processing tasks.
Warning: Permanently added '127.0.0.1' (RSA) t othe list of known host.
Error: Couldn't find me in the node map
```

The solution I was advised was to change a code in this source:

```
appscale/AppController/lib/helperfunctions.rb
```

And look for `self.local_ip()` and change to:

```
def self.local_ip()
  return "127.0.0.1"
end
```

But when I run

```
./appscale-run-instances --ips ips.yaml
```

I am not sure, but it just keep on saying:
`"Please wait for the controller to finish pre-processing tasks."`  for several minutes already.

So I decided to terminate it, and here is what I get:

```
"...common_functions.rb:399:in 'sleep_unti_port_is_open"
```

In this case, it seems I need to open a port, I am running AppScale from within Ubuntu, what port should I open in my server?

Here's the complete command line:

```
./appscale-run-instances --ips ips.yaml 

About to start AppScale over a non-cloud environment.
Head node successfully created at 127.0.0.1. 
It is now starting up cassandra via the command line arguments given. 
Generating certificate and private key.
Starting server at 127.0.0.1 

Please wait for the controller to finish pre-processing tasks. 

^C./../lib/../lib/common_functions.rb:399:in sleep': Interrupt
 from ./../lib/../lib/common_functions.rb:399:in 'sleep_until_port_is_open'
 from ./../lib/../lib/common_functions.rb:397:in 'loop'
 from ./../lib/../lib/common_functions.rb:397:in 'sleep_until_port_is_open' 
 from ./../lib/../lib/common_functions.rb:1359:in 'start_appcontroller' 
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:62:in ttimeout. 
 from ./../lib/../lib/common_functions.rb:1351:in 'start_appcontroller' 
 from ./../lib/../lib/common_functions.rb:548:in 'start_head_node' 
 from ./../lib/appscale_tools.rb:284:in trun_instances' 
 from ./appscale-run-instances:14
```

Comment: Hmm, is there anything else in the stack trace where it says `sleep_until_port_is_open`? AppScale is waiting for a particular port to open, but it should be managing the ports for you (so in this case, it's waiting for a service to come up, identified by a specific port).

Comment: Here's the complete command line: http://pastebin.com/heGdKP39

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the pre-build Appscale images [here](http://www.appscale.com/community/downloads/) or following the steps listed here https://github.com/AppScale/appscale/wiki/Virtualized-Cluster will solve this problem.

Also it has the build script:

```
$ sudo su
# cd /root
# wget -O - http://bootstrap.appscale.com | sh
```